# Regex engine optimization: Is `(?:.)*` really more costly than `.*`?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

**Some context**

I'm usually using the website http://regex101.com to test my regex, which provides a "debugger" feature in PCRE that lets you see what the regex engine is doing step by step.

When matching a random string with `.*`, this debugger tells me the engine follows the constant number of [3 steps](http://regex101.com/r/fJ4lC0/#debugger).

When matching with `(?:.)*`, it announces a number depending on the length: [66 steps](http://regex101.com/r/zS8wA7/#debugger) for something like `0123456789012345678901234567899`.

**Is `(?:.)*` really more costly than `.*`?**

It seems that on the latter case, entering the group is considered each time to be a new step, whereas on the former the `.*` is applied at once.

Is that some sort of "improvement" the website is doing (trying to avoid showing useless cases), or does it match a real internal regex mechanism ? And if so, what's the idea behind the scene?

Comment: I don't know about performance. That will be specific to the implementation. But `(?:.)*` doesn't offer any benefit over `.*` but it does make your syntax longer.

Comment: This question reeks of micro-optimization. While it's interesting from a purely academical point of view, I sincerely hope you're not assuming (without a very solid basis, at any rate) that the minute-yet-measurable difference between these two constructs will in any way offer a tangible benefit to you.

Comment: +1 to @Vector Gorgoth. When optimizing regex patterns, you want to do so by reducing the possibility of backtracking so it's as close to zero as possible. That's how you'll get real performance boosts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify which engine. You mentioned PCRE, but you also tagged with Perl.

---

regex101 site shows that PCRE handles `.*` using one operation, but that doesn't mean that one operation is faster than the operations generated by the equivalent `(?:.)*`. Only benchmarking will tell, but `.*` will likely be marginally faster due to less overhead.

---

In Perl, they compile to exactly the same regex program (as you can see below), so they will perform identically.

```
>perl -Mre=debug -e"'0123456789012345678901234567899' =~ /.*/"
Compiling REx ".*"
Final program:
   1: STAR (3)
   2:   REG_ANY (0)
   3: END (0)
anchored(MBOL) implicit minlen 0
Matching REx ".*" against "0123456789012345678901234567899"
   0 <> <0123456789>         |  1:STAR(3)
                                  REG_ANY can match 31 times out of 2147483647...
  31 <901234567899> <>       |  3:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: ".*"

>perl -Mre=debug -e"'0123456789012345678901234567899' =~ /(?:.)*/"
Compiling REx "(?:.)*"
Final program:
   1: STAR (3)
   2:   REG_ANY (0)
   3: END (0)
anchored(MBOL) implicit minlen 0
Matching REx "(?:.)*" against "0123456789012345678901234567899"
   0 <> <0123456789>         |  1:STAR(3)
                                  REG_ANY can match 31 times out of 2147483647...
  31 <901234567899> <>       |  3:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "(?:.)*"
```

In both cases, the string is scanned for characters than aren't newlines, and that's it.

---

Note that no matter how many "steps" are taken, this cannot be done in constant time. `.` doesn't match newlines (without `/s`), so the regex engine must check each character it's about to match to see whether it's a newline or not.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. I assumed the computing time would increase linearly with the steps number, but I guess indeed there's no reason for it.

Comment: @Robin, The same *work* needs to be done, no matter how many *steps* are taken (whatever that means). Sure, there will be differences (which is why they decided to create the shortcut), but it's not going to be massive. ||| This reminds me questions that ask "How do I do something to each Foo without using a loop?" You can hide the loop in a function (e.g. `map`), but the loop is still there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pcretest](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/exim-doc-4.63/html/doc/pcretest.html) for seeing the differences. [Here](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html) is a nice tutorial.

Your first example obviously need few steps, then the second. On the left side with the `+` you see the position in the pattern, on the right side the matching position in the input.

1.) `/.*/CD` on str `0123456789012345678901234567899` with debugging modifiers `CD`

[image: pcretest1]

2.) `/(?:.)*/CD` same str

[image: pcretest2]

And that is, what really happens.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So it seems that there is indeed an optimization on `.*` that makes it constant time... And it also works with `[^!]*`, for example. do you have any idea on what principle it could rely?

Comment: @Robin, `.*` can't be done in constant time since `.*` means `[^\n]*` in both PCRE and Perl (unless you use `/s`). It's gotta check to make sure that each matching character isn't a newline.

Comment: @Robin I just counted 65 steps for `(?:.)*`. Might be, that the site you mentioned uses pcretest for debugging info. For `.*` it says 3 steps, where I could count two steps on this test. What principle it could rely on? Have no idea how the internal optimizations work.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small benchmark code to test this scenario. And your both regex returns almost the same time on performance. So not sure about which one is better.

However, I have changed your changed your regex `(?:.)*` into `(.)*` and it drastically reduce the performance. I believe it is because of the `group capturing`. Here is the code:

```
use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

cmpthese(-3, {    
    '.*'     => '"kasdaskdhas dhaskdh askdhqwioeuweakjsdhasjdk asjdk ask" =~ /.*/',
    '(?:.)*' => '"kasdaskdhas dhaskdh askdhqwioeuweakjsdhasjdk asjdk ask" =~ /(?:.)*/',
    '(.)*'   => '"kasdaskdhas dhaskdh askdhqwioeuweakjsdhasjdk asjdk ask" =~ /(.)*/',
});
```

Outputs:

```
            Rate   (.)* (?:.)*     .*
(.)*   2305921/s     --   -34%   -35%
(?:.)* 3499870/s    52%     --    -1%
.*     3524871/s    53%     1%     --
```

That 1% difference between `.*` and `(?:.)*` is noise and meaningless.

Comment: Re "So not sure about which one is better." Neither. They compile into the same regex program. Seem my answer.

Comment: @ikegami this the first time i wrote a code using benchmark module :D! Practice makes a man perfect, and someday I'll in terms of `benchmark`.

Comment: (`timethese` would give the times rather than the rate table, if you prefer)

Comment: `(.)*` is a different operation so the time difference doesn't surprise me, but both other solutions do seem to compile the same. Thanks for the benchmark, feels good to have numbers on this.

Answer (score 1):

The website doesn't seem to explain what those steps *are*!

This has to be an optimisation issue. The question *"Is `(?:.)*` really more costly than `.*?`"* depends on the regex engine in use, and the site is very unlikely to use Perl's regex engine which is built into the perl compiler/interpreter. The optimisation in whatever it *does* use has chosen to ignore trivial cases like `(?:.)*` that are unlikely in the real world.

If you need your regex to run faster then you should use [`Benchmark`](https://metacpan.org/module/Benchmark) to compare different patterns, or perhaps [`Regexp::Optimizer`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aOptimizer), which will attempt to rewrite your pattern into an equivalent faster one, or [`Regexp::Debugger`](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aDebugger) which will allow you to see what is going on behind the scenes.

But please don't take these measures until you have written a functional and clear program that doesn't perform fast enough, and have proven that the bottleneck is the regex matching. The regex engine is wholly written in C and you are unlikely to make a big difference to the overall speed of your code by changing the regex patterns that it uses.

Comment: Loading it into Regexp::Debugger is revealing.  Give it a try.

Comment: The site is using PHP's PCRE for the debugging. Obviously `(?:.)*` isn't likely to happen, I dumbed down the example to make it easier. One example would be something like `([^p]++|p(?!attern))*+`: is the inside `++` really relevant or not?

Comment: According to `rxrx`, the pattern `(?:.)*` takes 127 steps to walk through his input string.  The pattern `.*` takes three steps to accomplish the same match.

Comment: @DavidO, That means that `.*` is implemented as a single op in whatever engine `rxrx` uses, but says nothing about how fast is it versus the equivalent `(?:.)*`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the subject, but from what I can tell, yes, `/(?:.)*/` and `/(.)*/` are more costly than `/.*/`.

According to the Perl documentation  on [backtracking](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking),

> A fundamental feature of regular expression matching involves the
>   notion called backtracking, which is currently used (when needed) by
>   all regular non-possessive expression quantifiers, namely * , *? , + ,
>   +?, {n,m}, and {n,m}?. Backtracking is often optimized internally, but the general principle outlined here is valid.

So basically, `.*` is optimized internally, but I can't find a source that says how.

I also found another source, a [blog](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol1_2/tpj0102-0006.html) post by the author of [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124), Jeffrey Friedl.

> By the way, I guess I should make one mention about how Perl
>   sometimes optimizes how it deals with regular expressions. Sometimes
>   it might actually perform fewer tests than what I've described. Or it
>   perhaps does some tests more efficiently than others (for example,
>   /x*/ is internally optimized such that it is more efficient than
>   /(x)*/ or /(?:x)*/). Sometimes Perl can even decide that a regex can
>   never match the particular string in question, so will bypass the test
>   altogether.

If anyone else can explain the optimizations Perl makes in more detail, that would be useful!

Comment: I imagine the optimisations in Perl's regex compiler are too abstruse to explain by anything but the code itself, and that it varies from one release of Perl to the next. Regular expressions are already an arcane language, and writing a pattern with a view to the optimisations that the compiler will perform can only make them even more so. The Perl regex engine is *fast*, and you should just let it do its thing.

Comment: If you are truly interested in the optimisations that the regex compiler does, take a look at [the `regcomp.c` source here](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob_plain/fb5a6c43a8bf77b89047f06b2d3932698843b7c9:/regcomp.c). It is 17,000 lines of C